# Retrieve file list Server side Silverlight c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, file

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this out.

I have a Silverlight business app, with A DomainService included.

I would like to retrieve the list of files back to the Silverlight client, how can I incorporate this into a method.

And also if I were to use the path as .\ where would it's location be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pull files from the server, you need to run that code on the server (i.e. inside of your service).